# ¿Es posible agregar un elemento HTML antes del body?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

necesito agregar un elemento HTML antes del body y despues del head, de esta manera:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <ELEMENTO QUE DESEO AGREGAR>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

¿alguna idea de como se puede realizar usando javascript?

Comment: Nos muestras por favor que has tratado?

Comment: Agrega una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado/intentado como se sugiere en [ask].

Comment: Por poder puedes, gracias a la amable respuesta de @nauseantparrot, pero no estarías siguiendo los estándares de la W3C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes lograr tu cometido de una forma sencilla haciendo uso de la función `insertBefore`, te dejo un ejemplo agregando un elemento `div` con el cual puedas guiarte:

```
const theHtml = document.querySelector('html') // Obtengo el elemento html
const theBody = document.querySelector('body') // Obtengo el elemento body
const myDiv = document.createElement('div') // Se crea el elemento div

theHtml.insertBefore(myDiv, theBody) // Se inserta el div previamente al body
```